# Is there any keyword of function which can return the number of H1 tags present on the page?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to find out the number of componenets from the web page like H1 tag. How many H1 tags components are there on web page using robot framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Get Element Count` keyword from the [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Count). The following line should do:

```
${elementCount}    Get Element Count    tag:H1
Log to console     ${elementCount}
```

Comment: This should nail the OP